# DIV to onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I make the second DIV into an on click event? I have both of them displaying right now. I want to display one then when you click it displays the second one and back and forth.
I have never used HTML or JavaScript before so bear with me.

```
  <html>
  <head>
     <DIV class="container"><HGROUP>
       <H1>University of Illinois Hospital and Health Sciences</H1>
       <H2>Storage Availability Charts and Graphs</H2></HGROUP><NAV 
       class="navbar"></div>
  <DIV class="container">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Storage', 'Terabytes'],
         ['Raw',  95],
         ['Usable',  34],

      ]);

      var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        pieSliceText: 'label',
        title: 'EEI VNX5700',
        pieStartAngle: 100,
        is3D: true,
        };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
       }
     </script>
  </div>

  <DIV class="container">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
           var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Unallocated', 'Used', 'Free'],
           ['Cerner fast pool',  1000,      400],
           ['General fast pool',  1170,      460],
           ['Raid',  970,       644]
       ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Unallocated',
          vAxis: {title: 'Pools',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
       };

        var chart = new  google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
  </div>


  <body>
   <div id="piechart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>

  <body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>


  </head>
  </html>
```

Comment: *"How can I make the second DIV into an on click event?"* I assume you mean you want to **bind** an event handler to the element? Because you cannot convert a DOM element to an event, both are completely different things. If you want to learn about event handling, I suggest  to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: Your html markup is not correct. For example a [html-page can only have 1 `body`-Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element) that usually follows after the head-element.

Your code looks like that you are using [Google Charts (Pie Chart)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1). But you do not mention how the use of them plays together with your question. Could you clarify your question? How much do you know about html and javascript?

Comment: yes i am using Google charts, I'm trying to display one chart then display another one with more details and back and forth.I don't know much about html and JavaScript. I'm following a tutorial online but i haven't gotten to where i can do this. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok if you want a div to be hidden when the page loads you can do (in jquery) `$('#idOfDiv').hide()` then to get the div to toggle you can do a `$('#idOfDiv').toggle()` Now if you want something to be an onClick even all you have to do is put it all in a

```
$("#secondDiv").hide();
$( "#firstDiv" ).click(function() {
    $('#secondDiv').toggle(); 
});
$( "#secondDiv" ).click(function() {
    $('#firstDiv').toggle(); 
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/AFPT2/1/

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*.

Comment: Thanks @tcordero, if you don't mind can you post how everything would fit together in your example. And thank you all for the your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Also I cleaned up your html. All this should go in the <body></body> tags. None of it should be in your head tags.

Comment: @mikesmith no problem! Be sure to mark this question as answered so others that have the same question know how it was solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to switch visibilities you should give them each a seperate id.

Then you will need to use javascript (jquery is an easy way to work with javascript)

The jquery code would look something like this

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
     $('#div2').show();
     $('#div1').hide();
});

$('#div2').click(function(){
     $('#div1').show();
     $('#div2').hide();
});
```

To use jquery get the library here: http://jquery.com/

If you don't want to use jquery here are simple show/hide functions:

```
<script> 
    function show(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById(id).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById(id).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }   
</script>
```

then just add those to your div onclick: `<div id='div1' onclick='show("div2");hide("div1")'></div>`

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*. Also, *"jquery is an easy way to do javascript"* is not quite right. jQuery makes working with the DOM easier, but not JavaScript.